# How to select the content inside a div using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, selector

I believe the answer may be quite simple but i cant find the answer by searching.

What i would like to do is to change the contents of a div using jquery. Currently i am using this (which does work, but is not the most elegant solution)

What is the best way to select this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#score-once").click(function ()  {
        var numRand = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
        var currValue = parseInt($("#scored").text());
        var newValue = (currValue + numRand);
        $("#scored").replaceWith("<p id=scored>" + newValue + "</p>")
        currValue = undefined;
        newValue = undefined;
    });     
});
```

and the html

```
        <div id="sidebar">
            Goals Scored<br />
            <p id="scored">0</p>
            Goals Missed<br />
            <p>0</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not the most elegant? Looks ok to me :-)

Comment: Having to replace the entire paragraph tag rather than just replacing the content + undefining variables (which im not even sure i have to do!). Or maybe im just over criticizing my own work ;)

Comment: undefining you don't have to do. The rest is ok. Move on to the next task :-)

Comment: you kinda are lol. you could also go for `$('#scored').html("content here");` to change the contents if the p ;)

Comment: The only thing i suggest is using this instead of `replaceWith` - ` $("#scored").text(newValue );`

Comment: Just tried that Teun, that was actually exactly what i was looking for! Could you put it as an answer and i can give you some rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tiny improvement:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#score-once").click(function ()  {
        var numRand = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
        var currValue = parseInt($("#scored").text());
        var newValue = (currValue + numRand);
        $("#scored").text(newValue)
    });     
});
```

It probably can't get any better than this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `.html()` function should do the trick.

```
$("#scored").html(newValue);
```